# Convert comma separated varchar to numeric without replace

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2012, decimalformat

Are there any way in t-sql to get from varchar like `12,3` numeric parameter `12.3` without using

```
    select cast(replace('12,3',',','.') as numeric(12,2))
    select cast(cast('12,3' as money) as numeric(12,2))/10
```

Something like

```
    ALTER SESSION SET NLS_NUMERIC_CHARACTERS =','
```

in Oracle PL/SQL.

Comment: Well, the usual answer would be "don't store numbers as strings". Why are you doing that?

Comment: I need to parse json that includes many numeric parameters.

Comment: You're parsing JSON in T-SQL? I think you've picked the wrong technology for the task :) You should probably handle that in server code, or if you really need to store documents in MS SQL, you should use XML rather than JSON - XML is a native in MS SQL, unlike JSON.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From SQL Server 2012 you can use [PARSE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh213316.aspx) with a culture that use comma as decimal separator.

```
select parse('12,3' as numeric(12,2) using 'sv-SE')
```